# scp + Avoid copy if the same file name located on remote machine?

Tags: linux, bash, scp

Is there any option to tell scp command - not copy file from current machine in case file exists on remote machine

For example

On my machine I have the file -

```
/etc/secret-pw.txt
```

On Remote machine I have also the file -

```
/etc/secret-pw.txt
```

So

```
scp /etc/secret-pw.txt $remote_machine:/etc
```

Will destroy the **secret-pw.txt**, and scp will not ask questions about: overwrite the target file

Is there any option to avoid copy if file exist on target machine by scp?

**Update:** I can't install rsync or any other program.

Comment: in my bash script + expect script  I use the scp command - to copy files between  one machine to a nothers

Comment: Do you have GNU tar on both sides?

Comment: about the tar command I guess yes ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) instead of `scp`. It will give you what you need.

If you can't install `rsync` (as you mentioned in the comments) you need to run a script beforehand to check if file exists and run it with `ssh`.

Comment: I don’t have rsync installed on my Linux box , And I cant to installed that command ( because some internal issues )

Comment: Are you able to use Unison?

Answer (score 0):

SCP does not offer any option, unfortunately.

But you can resort standard tools, like this:

```
ssh $remote_machine -- cp --no-clobber /dev/stdin /etc/secret-pw.txt < /etc/secret-pw.txt
```

Note that with this trick you gain all the functionalities of `cp`.

Comment: or: `ssh $remote_machine -- cp --no-clobber /dev/stdin /etc/secret-pw.txt < /etc/secret-pw.txt`